# Is it possible to employ use logic when back referencing with relationships in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy, orm

In SQLAlchemy, we can create a table for `Parent` and `Child` like below -

```
class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    children = relationship("Child", back_populates="parent")

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'child'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parent.id'))
    parent = relationship("Parent", back_populates="children")
    age = Column(Integer)
```

If now I want to add an attribute to `Parent` that says `oldest_child_age` that uses the linked children's age and then compute the max of all the parent's children. How do I do that? Then ideally when I add to the database another older child, the corresponding parent should have the `oldest_child_age` automatically refreshed to that older child (assuming that child is the oldest among all existing children).

Thanks!!